# How to apply committed changes from Repo1 to Repo2 with VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github

I'm learning some jekyll by working on a personal project, and I decided to use two separate repos for my experiments.

I started doing simple stuff in Repo1, then made a Repo2 and got in the groove editing everything there, and now the Repo1 looks so far behind and different, I'd like for it to catch up, so to speak.

There are 500 commits in Repo2 ready to get synced to Github in the source control, I'd like to know what would be the best way to apply those same 500 commits from Repo2 to the Repo1, if possible using VSCode GUI since I'm not a professional.

Comment: set each repo as a remote in the other repo, then push to the alternative remote, do both repos have the same initial commit

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but if by same initial commit you mean same files at the beginning of the process - yes. I have a theme that I use, so the theme files are what I started with in both repos, and eventually Repo1 was bit forgotten and Repo2 got all the attention and now I'd like to bring Repo1 up to speed in the most simple way :D

Comment: it is not if you use the same files in the initial commit per repo, but they need to have the same commit hash, and also the rest of the commit history until the update stop of Repo1

Comment: So you're saying my initial setup is not correct for this? What should I do then, ditch this idea, how would I then take Repo2 and make a new repo that is identical to it?

Comment: you can copy the whole directory of Repo2 to Repo1, but why if they are on the same machine, why keep Repo1

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

1. Don't do anything - keep two independent repos.
2. Abandon Repo1:  Create a new branch in Repo2 and just copy the changes from Repo1 to this new branch and then merge this new branch to your Repo2's main branch (or keep it as a branch forever)
3. Get changes from Repo2 to Repo1 (your explicit wish): Make Repo2 a `remote` for Repo1. Inside Repo1:

   1. `git remote add repo2 <local_path_to_repo2>` or `git remote add repo2 url_of_repo2_in_github`
   2. `git fetch repo2`
   3. e.g. `git merge repo2/main`

Please remember that the more elaborate structure you come up with the harder it is to keep things in sync. Maybe a single repo is OK or mayb 2 independent repos?

Comment: Thank you for suggestions! I like the option 3 because that's what I want to achieve, I want both of these sites I built on a Jekyll theme deployed on Netlify each in their own instance, coming from two separate repos in Github, and having one site in one repo looking almost perfect, I want the other site from other repo get up to speed with all changes.